# Openlayers zoom-based object visibility not working

Tags: javascript, zooming, openlayers

I would like to have my element zoom-based. I don't need it visible when zooming out of 19, because my map doesn't look nice.

[image]

I tried to use the `maxResolution` method derived from the `layers.js` file, when it was found, as a whole map was generated by the QGIS2web plugin.
Unfortunately it wasn't working

I tried also the `minZoom` feature, but in vain.

All the reasonable examples I found here:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-zoom-limits.html

https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/issues/51

Another thread says about changing the maxResolution value, but it didn't work either.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160725/vector-layer-visibility-using-min-maxresolution-is-not-working-in-openlayers-2

Finally, my code looks as follows:

```
   var tekst2 = new ol.Overlay({
   position: pos3,
   minZoom: 19,
   element: document.getElementsByClassName('tekscio')[1],
   });
   map.addOverlay(tekst2);
```

I see, that the minZoom refers mostly for the lower zoom limit of the map canvas.

But this configuration:

```
  var tekst2 = new ol.Overlay({
  position: pos3,
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('tekscio')[1],
  maxResolution:0.42006699228392946,
  });
  map.addOverlay(tekst2);
```

didn't work either.

I also found some methods here:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/deprecated-js.html

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/FixedZoomLevels-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.FixedZoomLevels.getOLZoomFromMapObjectZoom

but it looks like they have been deprecated.

What should I do in this code? Is there another thing to provide here, which I am missing?

I want to have this text based on the zoom level.

Just in case I am sending the JS fiddle with the javascript code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/uxkcyomf/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], in your question itself, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers),  not (just) a link to an external (non-working) example/fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have my element zoom-based. I don't need it visible when zooming out of 19, because my map doesn't look nice.

You can simply show/hide an element depending on the current zoom level in a way similar to this (the zoom change handler was taken from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309404/70847):

```
var currZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
map.on("moveend", function(e) {
  var newZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
  if (currZoom != newZoom) {
    if (newZoom > 19) {
        document.getElementById("vienna").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("vienna").style.display = "unset";
    }
    currZoom = newZoom;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!